# microphone selection to record boiling of water

Tags: humidity, temperature

I want to record boiling sound of water with less surrounding noise and trying to record as much detail it can be . please suggest me an affordable microphone who can does the job and can give me much nicer data to process.

Answer (score -1):

Boiling water has collapsing bubbles: you really want a very no-nonsense mic for that in order to keep the phases.  Measurement microphones are usually omnidirectional but with moderate SNR ratio, so the noisiness may be a problem.  However, any microphone is going to be unhappy about vapors, though the ones taking damage fastest may be electret condensers.  So you want to keep some distance from the steam.  Maybe put up a slanted metal sheet over your pot that will deflect the sound sideways while the steam sort-of continues upwards?

So in short: you'll have to take a number of compromises: I don't see an obvious "best way" here.